# Замена содержимого в файле ОТ и ДО с помощью плагина для nodejs + vite (webpack)

Tags: node.js, webpack, vite

Изучаю написание web части для wifi модуля. Использую **Preact+nodejs+vite (webpack)...** для создания Frontend.

Есть файл **WebAssets.h** (текстовый файл) с содержимым:

```
const char index_html[] PROGMEM = R"=====(<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Device Manager</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
)=====";
```

Мне нужно найти начало `const char index_html[] PROGMEM = R"=====(` и конец `)=====";` и в этот промежуток вставить текст из другого файла, который генерируется при сборке проекта `index.html`

Как это сделать?

Answer (score 0):

Пришлось самому писать функцию, ничего не нашел.
По итогу вышло это:

```js
// Функция замены текста в файле
/* Принимает: путь к файлу, начальную и конечную строку, новый контент */
function replace(path, startString, endString, newContent) {
  /* Считываем содержимое файла в строку */
  const fileContent = fs.readFileSync(path, 'utf-8');
  /* Находим индексы начальной и конечной строки */
  const startStr = startString;
  const endStr = endString;
  const startIndex = fileContent.indexOf(startStr);
  const endIndex = fileContent.indexOf(endStr);
  /* Вставляем текст между указанными строками */
  if (startIndex !== -1 && endIndex !== -1) {
    const modifiedContent =
      fileContent.substring(0, startIndex) +
      fileContent.substring(startIndex, startIndex + startStr.length) +
      newContent +
      fileContent.substring(endIndex, endIndex + endStr.length) +
      fileContent.substring(endIndex + endStr.length);
    /* Записываем измененное содержимое обратно в файл */
    fs.writeFileSync(path, modifiedContent);
  } else {
    console.error('Начальная и/или конечная строка не найдены в файле');
  }
}

// Ну и сам вызов
// Прочитать файл в переменную
const index_html = fs.readFileSync('./index.html', 'utf-8');
// Вызвать функцию замены
replace( FileReplace, 'R"-=html=-(', ')-=html=-', index_html );
```

Получается:

- читаем файл index.html в переменную index_html
- вызываем функцию замены
- передаем путь к редактируемому файлу
- начальный текст R"-=html=-(
- конечный текст )-=html=-
- контент из файла index.html

В итоге в строку вида `const char index_html[] PROGMEM = R"-=html=-(gdfbdfgbd)-=html=-";` вместо `gdfbdfgbd` подставится содержимое index.html